# No Method Error, not able to save data to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I encountered some problem when trying to save data into database. The error keep pointing to the CREATE action @invoices = @permits.build_invoice(). Stating undefined method `build_invoice' for nil:NilClass NO METHOD ERROR. Anyone know how to fix it?

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:permit_id])
    @invoice = Invoice.new
  end

  def create
    #@current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])

    @invoices = @permits.build_invoice(invoice_params)
    if @invoices.save
      redirect_to payment_path
    else

    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_invoice
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def invoice_params
    params.require(:invoice).permit(:vehicle_type, :name, :department, :carplate, :duration, :permitstart, :permitend, :price, :time)
  end
end
```

Permit.rb

```
class Permit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :invoice
end
```

Invoice.rb

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :receipt
  belongs_to :permit
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`@permits` is nil. You haven't assigned anything to that variable.
It should also be 1 permit and 1 invoice, according to your model.

```
def create
  @permit = Permit.find(params[permit_id])
  @invoice = @permit.invoice.new(invoice_params)
  if @invoices.save
    redirect_to payment_path
  else
    #catch error here
  end
end
```

Comment: I got back the error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvoicesController#create Couldn't find Permit with 'id'= which same with the other provided solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `@permits` in `create` scope. So you can use controller filter to find `@permits` for `new` and `create`

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_permit, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    # Remove it @permits = Permit.find(params[:permit_id])
    @invoice = Invoice.new
  end

  # your other codes

  private

  def find_permit
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:permit_id])
  end
end
```

Btw, you should rename `@permits` to `@permit`, a singular form makes more sense!

Comment: Alright, I will change it :). I tried your solution but I got back this error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvoicesController#create
Couldn't find Permit with 'id'= Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `permit_id` from your view / API call.

Change your create method like below.

```
  def create
    #@current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])

    @permit = Permit.find(params[:permit_id])
    @invoices = @permit.build_invoice(invoice_params)
    if @invoices.save
      redirect_to payment_path
    else

    end
  end
```

Comment: I tried your solution and got back this error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvoicesController#create
Couldn't find Permit with 'id'=

Comment: Post you params here. Like, add "puts params" in your top of create method and copy that parameters printed in the log and paste it here as a comment.

Comment: Is it this is the one you need? {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"p2ZAttQtKfvKvdl87/C1dLn0UoyJSBYys76BkNTEZnG+de/MKHGBImlXW8Nm4wWHz8Gd0q9ShbqICI5G/EUSOw==", "invoice"=>{"price"=>"$AUD 50"}, "commit"=>"Make Payment"}

Comment: permit_id is not passed from your view as params, thats why you are getting exception. You should pass actual permit_id from your view to access it in controller.

Comment: From my view? How should I pass it from my view. In my program user will redirect from a Permit page to the invoice page by createinvoice_path(permit_id: @permits.id) in the Permit controller. I though I already sent the permitid to the invoice page?

Comment: It might be for new invoice path. So note that new_invoice_path is different from create_invoice_path. new_invoice path will render the new invoice page html. But create_invoice_path is POST method which is different route from new_invoice_path to save the invoice in database. Probably you might had a button in your new invoice page where you might had a save button. When clicking on that button it will call the create method in your invoice controller. In that, the permit_id should be passed. You should pass permit_id from create invoice page to access it in create method in your controller.

Comment: Yes I think I managed to solve the problem by adding this line <%= hidden_field_tag(:permit_id, @permits.id) %> which i found online to pass the permit_id when you press the SUBMIT button. Thanks for your suggestion! But now I met another problem which I cant save the model to the db :(

Comment: If you want help for that, open a new question. Try to up vote for the answer.